# format of result in sunspot-solr

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot-solr

Im using Sunspot Solr in Rails. My code looks as below :

```
searchable do
  text :title, :stored => true
  string :id, :stored => true
  integer :status, :stored => true
end
```

and In my controller, after performing the search when I go to store it in a hash:

```
one_result= {:title => hit.stored(:title), :id => hit.stored(:id)}
```

now when I do `puts one_result.inspect`, I get:

```
{"title": ["THIS IS TITLE"]
 "id":12345
}
```

The problem is that all the text field become array `[..]`. I want to include the results in a json response. I want it to be :

```
{"title": "THIS IS TITLE"
 "id":12345
}
```

Any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the fieldType for the field "Title" is defined as multivalued="true" in schema.xml.

Please make it as false so that you get it as a string.

Comment: Please help me with this  : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31512210/indexing-using-two-tables-in-sunspot-solr-rails-4