# Indexing using two tables in sunspot solr + rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot-solr

I'm using sunspot-solr in ROR and I need help in creating a searchable block using two tables.(join of two tables)
The query I want to be executed when the indexes are formed is :

```
SELECT a.id,a.title
FROM table_one a,table_two b 
WHERE a.status=1 
AND a.id=b.id 
AND b.status=1
```

I want the "title" field to be searchable(text), only if the id exists in both tables and both have status 1.And I want them to be stored fields(no db hits).

```
class TableOne
  has_many :table_twos
 searchable do
  text :title, :stored => true
  string :status, :stored => true
  string :id, :multiple => true, :stored => true do
         table_twos.map(&:id)
 end
end
```

When I searched a word, I got 5 results.

But when I delete an entry of one of the results from table_two and searched the same word again.. I still got 5 results when I should get only the other 4.

Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

If you delete an associated record that was stored as a solr/sunspot record, you will have no choice but to reindex that record.

Comment: I reindexed after deleting a record from table_two... but I still get it in the search results : `"title": "THIS IS THE TITLE", "id": null`....I don't want id as null. I want it to not come up as a search result at all ...

Answer (score 0):

So to solve the issue I did somthing like `without(:id,nil)` in my controller and I got the results as I wanted them.

I'm not sure its the right way to go about it though.